# how to send mail(smtp) in telnet with special character "."

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

This mail will be sent with a line of "."  However,if i want to set a line of "." in my body mail, how can i do?

```
telnet 192.168.1.1 25
HELO felix
MAIL FROM: <user@host.examplex.com>
RCPT TO: <user@host.examplex.com>
DATA
From: "support" <support@felix.cn>
To: <jqye@felix.cn>
Subject: Test mail

Test mail
Body of email
End
.
QUIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is 'Dot followed by space'.

Every time a line starts with a dot, you should actually send two dots.
eg.:

..

Should give you the desired result: A single dot.
The server would then remove the first dot.
This is also known as 'dot-stuffing' (try looking it up).
See also [SMTP dot stuffing - who does it and who removes it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971703/smtp-dot-stuffing-who-does-it-and-who-removes-it)